# Shopware 6 Admin Api: How to build url

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

I want to provide dynamic link like this from the produuct index page with filter set:

```
/sw/product/index?limit=25&page=1&sortBy=productNumber&sortDirection=DESC&naturalSorting=false&grid.filter.product=%257B%2522visibilities-filter%2522%253A%257B%2522value%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%252298432def39fc4624b33213a56b8c944d%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Headless%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522criteria%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522equalsAny%2522%252C%2522field%2522%253A%2522visibilities.salesChannel.id%2522%252C%2522value%2522%253A%252298432def39fc4624b33213a56b8c944d%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D
```

... decoded:

```
/sw/product/index?limit=25&page=1&sortBy=productNumber&sortDirection=DESC&naturalSorting=false&grid.filter.product={"visibilities-filter":{"value":[{"id":"98432def39fc4624b33213a56b8c944d","name":"Headless"}],"criteria":[{"type":"equalsAny","field":"visibilities.salesChannel.id","value":"98432def39fc4624b33213a56b8c944d"}]}}
```

I try likle this:

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'sw.product.index', query:{
    'grid.filter.product':{
        'visibilities-filter':{
            'value':[{'id':'98432def39fc4624b33213a56b8c944d','name':'Headless'}],
            'criteria':[{
                'type':'equalsAny',
                'field':'visibilities.salesChannel.id',
                'value':'98432def39fc4624b33213a56b8c944d'
            ]}
        }
}}">
    0 Produkte zugeordnet
</router-link>
```

But the generated url is:
`http://0.0.0.0:8080/#/sw/product/index?grid.filter.product=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

I'm looking for a way to encode correctly the parameter. Is there maybe a doc?

Answer (score 0):

Combination `JSON.stringify()` & `encodeURIComponent()` **works** :

```
...
filter() {
 const obj = {
  'visibilities-filter':{
   'value':[{'id':'98432def39fc4624b33213a56b8c944d','name':'Headless'}],
   'criteria':[{
     'type':'equalsAny',
     'field':'visibilities.salesChannel.id',
     'value':'98432def39fc4624b33213a56b8c944d'
   ]}
 }
}

const string = JSON.stringify(obj)

return encodeURIComponent(string)
}
```